# Obtain specific user (not current user) domain name from Active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

While I realise that there is a lot of material online relating to this issue, there doesn't seem to be a lot for this specific issue.

I am looking to query Active Directory in C# to not only obtain the user name, but the user's domain name also. I am NOT looking for the domain name of the current user or current session.

The reason for this is that many users will be from multiple domains and will not be on the same name as the administrator that is manipulating a user's credentials via the U.I.

So when the admin adds a user, I need to check the user's domain name and input that preceding the users name e.g. DOMAIN\username
As the added user's domain name might not necessarily be the same as the previously added user.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want to query against and what you need to return. And how come when an admin adds a user he whould not know what domain he is adding the user to?

Comment: I am looking to return the domain of the specific user that is added by the admin. The admin will/should know the domain of the user, however this is to prevent human error and time by automatically adding the domain name along with the user name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So the netbios name of the domain being the first component of the domain in the userPrincipalName (e.g. brian@contoso.com being CONTOSO\brian) is purely coincidental. There is absoutely no reason they have to match in AD.

The place to get the netBIOS name of the user's domain is from that domain's crossRef object. In order to do this, you need to get the domain portion of the user's distinguishedName (that's the portion of the string starting with DC=) and then search the configuration NC for the matching crossRef using a filter like this: (&(objectClass=crossRef)(ncName=)). You can then inspect the nETBIOSName attribute.

To get the DN of the configuration NC to root your search in, you can ask LDAP://RootDSE for the configurationNamingContext attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use LDAP. That will let you connect and query different domains. The full name is stored as a userprincipal eg username@domainname.com

You'll still need to know which tree to connect to though for a given domain name. Also, unless the domains are in a forest, you could get duplicate domain usernames if you're searching purely on username.

If the domains are in a forest, there is a shortcut where you can search on the forest root using the global catalog. You'll then be searching in every child domain. This may take a while though, dependant on the size of the tree to search.

**Edit**

these are some code fragments for checking LDAP that I've used. You should be able to put them together into something useful.

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(_Parser.Host, _Parser.Port));
connection.Bind(new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_Parser.Username, _Parser.Password));
```

x--- snip

```
request = new SearchRequest();
request.Filter = query;
request.Scope = SearchScope.Subtree;
request.DistinguishedName = _Parser.SearchBase;

response = (SearchResponse)connection2.SendRequest(request);
```

The response contains a collection of results you can then enumerate to find the entry you're interested in.

An LDAP query uses reverse polish notation & the one i think you want is `(samaccountname=<your value here>)` replace  with the username you want to look for. you don't need to quote the value.

replace `_Parser.SearchBase` with a string that is the dn of the object you want to start searching from. this is probably your domain root, eg dc=somedomain,dc=com if you domain is somedomain.com
host should be the name of the AD server you want to connect to. Use 3268 for the port as that's the global catalog and since it's read-only is quicker and has all partition. specify the username you use to connect as username@somedomain.com.

Look for the attribute called userprincipalname. the msdn documentation should help you how on how to read a result object.

Simon

Comment: Hi @Simon, thanks for the response. Your answer makes sense to me, however just for a bit of additional information, I am using the getAllUsers() method from MembershipUserCollection. Would your solution still apply to this? When a user is added via the admin screen, we want to check the username's domain and concatenate it with the username and backslash e.g. DOMAIN + \ + username. THANKS!

Comment: Apologies if any of that was vague, the MembershipUserCollection object comes from the System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection class. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, you mentioned a userprincipal (username@domainname.com) Is there a way to return this value via the LDAP? If I could get that, I could parse out the domain name from there? Thanks.

Comment: userprincipalname is an LDAP property. it may or may not match your domain name. the domain\username format is referred to as legacy format in User & Computers control panel. Depending what it is in your setup, you may or may not have to do some additional lookup to translate to NTLM domain

Comment: I would do a custom LDAP check rather than use getallusers as that could return a lot of objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your response, much appreciated! Could you possibly elaborate on how I would go about doing a custom LDAP check? Thank you.